# querying for a string'ed number in lucene finds nothing

Tags: lucene

I have an existing index with some documents I'm trying to search.
When I search a "real textual" field, everything is OK.
When I try to search a field which is a number, the search gives 0 results.
The code is something like this (it is pylucene but the concept is the same):

```
dir = SimpleFSDirectory(File(indexDir))
analyzer = StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT)
searcher = IndexSearcher(dir)
query = QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, "id", analyzer).parse("902")
hits = searcher.search(query, MAX)
print hits.totalHits #gives me 0
```

a luke search (id:902) gives me empty results as well.
When I look at the Overview tab on luke it says this field is UTF-8 (string)

Anything I'm doing wrong?

**edit:**
It appears this happens on Fields that are indexed and has no Norm (according to the flags of luke).
Can someone explain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like answering my own questions but I believe this answer is an important reference.
The solution is put a NumericRange query with both numbers the number you seek (this time in java):

```
NumericRangeQuery.newIntRange("id", Integer.valueOf(902), Integer.valueOf(902),
true, true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using SimpleAnalyzer while indexing? It strips off numbers. Make sure you are using same analyzer while indexing and searching.

Comment: unfortunately I didn't make the index. Any ideas of analyzers I should try?

Comment: For testing don't use the StandardAnalyzer because it's complex. The basic analyzers to use are the WhitespaceAnalyzer and KeywordAnalyzer. The former splits your string into tokens by whitespace, whereas the latter does no tokenization and always gives your exact string as one token. To check the index side, get a list of all indexed terms and see if you can find any numbers on it.